# Applying cross validation on multioutput regressor and get multiple scoring metrics for each output parameter

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, cross-validation

I am trying to build a multioutput regression model. My X values contain 6 labels.

```
model = MultiOutputRegressor(RandomforestRegressor())
```

I am trying to run cross validation on this model using `cross_val_score` but I am only able to get a single value for every parameter. I tried passing a array of strings to the `scoring` argument, but it gives error. I also tried creating a custom scoring function as follows:

```
def model_evaluate(estimator, x, y):
    y_df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=list(ref_df.columns))
    y_pred = estimator.predict(x)
    y_pred_df = pd.DataFrame(y_pred, columns=list(ref_df.columns))
    metrics = {}

    for i in ref_df.columns:
        metrics[f"{i}-MAE"] = mean_absolute_error(y_df[i], y_pred_df[i])
        metrics[f"{i}-MAPE"] = mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_df[i], y_pred_df[i])
        metrics[f"{i}-EVS"] = explained_variance_score(y_df[i], y_pred_df[i])
        metrics[f"{i}-R2"] = r2_score(y_df[i], y_pred_df[i])


    return metrics
```

but it is also giving errors. How should I proceed so that I can get multiple scoring parameter for each output variable.